# OnEdit-trigger combined with cell-functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-custom-function

I have an onEdit-script which calculates the value of a cell based on the content of a row of other cells.
I need this script to be in an onEdit-trigger rather than a regular cell-function because I don't always want the calculation to be redone when the value in one of the targeted cells is changed, but instead it checks for certain conditions and recalculates only when those are met.

A small problem I'm having with this is that one of the cells that the onEdit-script reads data from contains a function rather than a simple number.
This causes a problem because sometimes when I enter data in a cell, it will trigger both this cell-function and the onEdit-script. And most of the time the oEdit-function runs before the cell-function finishes so the onEdit-function just picks up "Thinking" from this cell and thus it returns NaN.

So I guess a convenient solution to this would have been to make the onEdit-function wait for the "targeted" cells to finish their calculation but I don't think there is a way to do this?

Of course I could move the cell-function(which basically is a SUM-function with some added functionality) to the onEdit-script, which would solve the issue.

But to me it doesn't seem so nice having all interactivity in the onEdit-trigger. Or am I just being silly?

Or is there another approach I could take somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to replace your custom formula (that "thinks") with a regular spreadsheet formula if possible. And it seems to be your case, since it's just a SUM function with "added functionality". Probably a SUMIF will suffice.

If your function is indeed complicated and can't be written as regular formula (which I really doubt), the best solution would be indeed to move the calculation to the onEdit-trigger.

Regardless of your problem ,I always advise to not use custom formulas, they are really problematic. e.g. haven't you ran into the caching issue?

Comment: After reading this I experimented a bit with custom functions vs regular functions and found out that the regular ones are way faster and doesn't cause the "thinking-problem", so that's good to know I guess.
I did look into SUMIF and other functions but I didn't find any that seems to work so I guess I'll have to move it to the onEdit-trigger then.

Comment: And by the way, it might have been an exaggeration that it basically was a SUM-function. It checks a rows of cells and also checks the two top cells in the same column. It does two different things depending on what the value of the top cell. If it's type A then it compares the value of the cell with the last cell, then divides that value with the time-difference of the current column and the last column and adds the result to var totalSum that is to be returned. If it's type B then it just adds the value to var lastValue.That's problaby a bit confusing,sorry.But I couldn't explain it better=)

Comment: Oh, and what's that "caching issue"? I haven't run into any problems apart from the "thinking". And I suppose it might not be impossible to do this without a custom function, I'm not sure. But it gets so unreadable and unmaintainable with more complex scripts.

Comment: The "caching issue" happens when your function does not depend only on its parameters. Because Google caches the return value of your function and does not evaluate it again when the parameters are the same. This is a very common issue, difficult to get right when doing custom functions.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
at the beginning of your onEdit() script to force recalc before continuing.

http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_spreadsheetapp.html#flush

Comment: I think the problem is not that's doesn't recalc, but actually wait the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

To get onEdit to wait for the calculations, you might try:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  // ...some if-condition that makes sure the following sleep is not called whenever any cell in your spreadsheet is edited

  Utilities.sleep(1000); // 1000 is the amount of milliseconds
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)

Although using sleep is brittle, in case the calculations take more or less time than you anticipated. It can introduce timing issues which are hard to debug.

> So I guess a convenient solution to this would have been to make the onEdit-function **wait for the "targeted" cells** to finish their calculation but I don't think there is a way to do this?

To have the aforementioned if-condition reference targeted cells (a specific range), see these answers: [Google Spreadsheet SCRIPT Check if edited cell is in a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range)