# Create Google Script to send email when cell is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-notifications

This may sound like many other questions - but it's slightly different and I can't formulate an answer.

I have "Tasks" in column A, "Person Responsible" for task in column B, "Email" in column C, and Column D is blank for tracking completion.

When an edit is made to a cell in Column D( like an "X" for completed), I want send an email to the address specified in the corresponding row, with the corresponding task in the email subject/body.

Here is a link to a Google Spreadsheet to help illustrate

http://goo.gl/uFWGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any reason why with a minimum of work you couldn't achieve what you want.
please have a look [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range/17684329#17684329) to learn how to restrict the event source range by column and then use simply the Mailapp service like in [this tuto](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails?hl=en) and you'll have the pleasure to run an app that you wrote by yourself...

The next one will be even easier and so will be the one after... That process is called learning and we all have been trough this, believe me.