# Trigger function when a cell is changed by functions?

Tags: google-apps-script

The cell has a function `=AVERAGE()` or `=SUM()` and is changed, but `onedit ()` does not work, only if the cell is manually changed.

How to create a trigger for this case?

Comment: You can try the installable onChange trigger - but I don't think that an updated calculation qualifies as a "change".

Comment: You could make a custom function, like =customSum()

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do this, but if you're using a formula, the user may have made an edit somewhere, that affected the result.

For example, if you have the formula: `=SUM('A2:A50')`, one way to achieve what you want is verifying if the **edit** event happened inside that range `'A2:A50'`.

Here's an example code that might help:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var editedRange = e.range

  if (rangeContainsAnotherRange(yourRange,editedRange)){
    // Do whatever you want
  }

}

// Maybe not the most practical way to verify if one range is inside another
function rangeContainsAnotherRange(widerRange, editedRange){
  var editRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editedRange.getColumn();

  var widerRangeRowStart = widerRange.getRow();
  var widerRangeRowEnd = widerRangeRowStart + widerRange.getHeight();
  var widerRangeColStart = widerRange.getColumn();
  var widerRangeColEnd = widerRangeColStart + widerRange.getWidth();

  return (editRow >= widerRangeRowStart && editRow <= widerRangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= widerRangeColStart && editCol <= widerRangeColEnd)

}
```

Hope that helps.

For the example above, on the `onEdit` function, the variable `yourRange` would be a range `'A2:A50'`.

Obs: *[Reference for the second function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range)*