# google sheets - send email notification based on time of day

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In google sheets, is there a way to send an email notification when a  cell is not filled by a certain time of the day? Like if cell A1 isn't filled by 5pm, send an email to user to tell them to fill that cell.

Comment: @user320704 can you show me how that is done using the time trigger? Sorry I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [Time driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) that checks if the cell(or range) is blank and then calls a [email function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)

Also look at this SO answer, which uses [OnEdit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range)