# How can I set a range in a Google script so if the a row is edited, a timestamp is produced?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Here is the script I have so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,30).setValue(new Date())
}
```

The issue is I need to be able to edit certain fields without it triggering a new date. There's a clean range of cells that I need the script to work (I5:O60) on but can't figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583187/google-spreadsheet-script-check-if-edited-cell-is-in-a-specific-range

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Enter your sheet name" && e.range.rowStart > "some row number") {
    e.range.offset(0,"enter number of column you want the date in").setValue(new Date());
  } 
}
```